# Bootstrap - Page Division

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using bootstrap. I have got my page ready with header and footer. But I want to divide my container in to left and right part.

[image: Layout]

What can be the bootstrap way to do it? so my page can be flexible enough on different devices?

**home.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/views/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/views/css/home.css"/>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <div class="container" style="display: table; width: 100%;padding:  0px;">
        <p class="muted-text">This is container</p>
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="includes/footer.jsp"></jsp:include>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap Grid is what you are looking for:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of all columns is 12 so you can try something like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">Left col</div>
     <div class="col-md-8">Right col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can combine classes to create more flexible layouts.

- 'xs' *(mobile devices)*
- 'sm' *(small devices like tablets)*
- 'md' *(laptops, medium screen)*
- 'lg' *(larger screen)*

  For more info visit: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code for which works on all screens.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Left col</div>
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8">Right col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`col-sm` for small screen `col-md` for medium screen `col-lg` for large screen `col-xs` for extra small screen

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid

try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">LEFT</div>
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/375/

More examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp